# Weird bash/jarsigner behavior with storepass that contains !p

Tags: bash, jarsigner

I'm trying to call

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore /some-path/releasekey.keystore -storepass ******!p /some-file/path
```

in bash.

The `!p` at the end of my storepass keeps getting treated as a bang and is replaced with with the last command I called that started with p.

I can't change the this key, but is there anyway I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved - just changed the storepass